# Does an AC voltage source introduce transients in the circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, transient

For past several days, I have been struggling with a concept. Suppose you connect an AC voltage source in series with resistor and capacitor.  As the magnitude of the voltage source is changing continuously, shouldn't there be transient response in the circuit at each interval of time?

I asked ChatGPT regarding this. It said that, initially there will be a transient response and after some time the capacitor will have sufficient time to catch up to the changing voltage at lower frequency.

When the AC source voltage is changing rapidly, i.e. at high frequency, there will a transient response at every instant of time.

Can someone clarify this thing to me? Please recommend some sources where I can find an in depth explanation.

Comment: Don't ask chatgpt questions you want actual answers to. I've yet to see a single case where it spits out an answer that's actually correct, and not just very confident-seeming nonsense.

Answer (score 4):

> voltage source in series with resister and capacitor

I presume you're taking them in order (also, resist***o***r), so it will look like an RC lowpass. In that case, all you need is the convolution integral, since the impulse response can be easily found. The transfer function and impulse response will look like this:

$$\begin{align}
H(s)&=\dfrac{1}{RCs+1} \tag{1} \\
h(t)&=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\big(H(s)\big)=\exp\left(-\dfrac{t}{RC}\right) \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

To find out the response of a sine stimulus:

$$\begin{align}
s(t)&=\sin(2\pi ft) \\
y(t)&=h(t)\star s(t) \\
{}&=\int_{\tau=0}^t{\left(h(t-\tau)\cdot\sin(2\pi f\tau)\right)\mathrm{d}\tau} \\
{}&=\dfrac{\sin(2\pi ft)-2\pi fRC\cos(2\pi ft)}{4\pi^2f^2RC^2+1}+\dfrac{2\pi fRC}{4\pi^2f^2RC^2+1}\exp\left(-\dfrac{t}{RC}\right) \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

If you were to plot this you'd get this graph:

[image: formula]

And compare it to the actual response of the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2falgus.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: SPICE confirms]

So, yes, there will be an initial transient, represented by the second term in (3), which will always have some sort of an exponential attached to it, and the actual sine output, represented by the first term in (3), which wil be the *steady-state* of the output (long after the transients have all decayed).

Answer (score 0):

> Does an AC Voltage source introduce transient in the circuit?

AC can introduce "repetitive" transient at every cycle.
Just look a serial circuit with a voltage source, a diode, a inductor an a resistor.

[image]

i(L2) is a steady state waveform, i(L1) is a "repetitive" transient.